# Why isn't my static member function recognised across assemblies?

Tags: import, assemblies, c++-cli, generics

I have a helper assembly which includes a function to identify object types:

```
namespace Util
{
    using namespace System;

    public ref class CastingHelpers
    {
    public:
        template < class T, class U > 
        static System::Boolean isinst(U u);

        static bool Test() {return true;}
    };
}
```

...but for some reason, when I try and use it in a gui application which references the assembly:

```
Util::CastingHelpers::Test();

Util::CastingHelpers::isinst<SomeClass^>(someInstance);
```

..gives me an error:

```
2>.\DataProcessor.cpp(161) : error C2039: 'isinst' : is not a member of 'Util::CastingHelpers'
```

Note that test works fine. Is this something to do with the fact that isinst uses generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a generic function, you are creating a C++ template function which is not exported from the assembly.

Use the keyword `generic` instead of `template` to create .NET generic types and methods.

The template method is only visible by code that #includes its declaration.